# Pi Zero + Phat DAC connect to Bluetooth/3.5mm Speaker

Tags: audio, pi-zero, phat-dac

I am thinking about buying the Pi Zero kit [here](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Raspberry-Pi-Zero-Project-Kits/dp/B01G407VGK/ref=aag_m_pw_dp?_encoding=UTF8&m=A2UN2R4H88G8VB).

Would it work with a [UE Boom 2](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Bluetooth-Wireless-Speaker-Waterproof-Shockproof/dp/B0141208EA)? It has a 3.5mm jack plug and bluetooth connectivity.

Answer (score 3):

You could use the bluetooth function like this:

- Get a Micro USB to USB adapter and a USB BlueTooth adapter ([here](http://uk.shop.com/TRIXES+Raspberry+Pi+Micro+Bluetooth+2+0+Dongle-1479091846-p+.xhtml?sourceid=309&gclid=Cj0KEQiAiMHEBRC034nx2ImB1J0BEiQA-r7ctk9daKWH3jC7eKXZisrdOY6L6Firv07MutqMzP0Yi54aAgAV8P8HAQ) and [here](http://www.miniinthebox.com/usb-2-0-a-female-to-micro-b-male-converter-otg-adapter-cable-for-samsung-lg-htc-assorted-color_p2085850.html?currency=GBP&litb_from=paid_adwords_shopping&sku=429_6917&utm_source=google_shopping&utm_medium=cpc&adword_mt=&adword_ct=153432439327&adword_kw=&adword_pos=1o20&adword_pl=&adword_net=g&adword_tar=&adw_src_id=9772115911_686639719_34986925883_aud-146622001962:pla-255914862867&gclid=Cj0KEQiAiMHEBRC034nx2ImB1J0BEiQA-r7cttWAlI1cghQx90P3hKlwNMF3_vMLawxTzeF2WSCgVvgaAiwi8P8HAQ));
- Connect the adapter the the Pi's Micro USB port (the one labeled USB, not PWR) and the dongle to the USB port on the adapter;
- Update Raspbian with `sudo apt-get upgrade && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` as the newest version contains a BlueTooth connection utility.

Or, if you wanted to use the audio jack, you could route the audio out through the GPIO and connect it to a jack plug to bare ends wire (like [this](http://www.frontx.com/cpx507_v2.html)). You would hook up the audio jack's right channel to GPIO12 and it's left channel to GPIO13, and it's ground to any of the Pi's Gnd pins. You then run `pigs m 12 0 && pigs m 13 0` (Full instructions are [here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/49600/how-to-output-audio-signals-through-gpio/49661), and the pinout of the header on the audio jack cable is on the website).

Comment: The pHAT DAC appears to have an RCA audio connector (right/left jacks) already, so all you would need is an appropriate cable (RCA -> 3.5mm, male-to-male).