# Facing problems with audio output from GPIO pins with RPi 4

Tags: gpio, pi-4, audio, retropie, config.txt

I am unable to get audio output from the GPIO pins on my Raspberry Pi 4.

I initially added `dtoverlay=pwm-2chan,pin=18,func=2,pin2=13,func2=4` to the config.txt file in boot directory and used the GPIO pins 13 and 18 with filters to get audio output following [this video](https://youtu.be/3pXB90IDNoY) but was unable to get any sound (there was only white noise).

I searched on the internet and found [this answer](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/122313/134017), but it was still unclear to me whether `dtoverlay=audremap,pins_12_13` and `dtoverlay=audremap,pins_18_19` also need to be added, or only one, or do one of these replace the line mentioned before. Regardless, I tried a a lot combinations and so far nothing has worked. Every time I run `sudo raspi-config` and go to Audio, the two options are always 'HDMI 1' and 'Headphones'.

I apologize if I sound annoyed, but the fact that there is no explanation anywhere as to *what* dtoverlay=blah blah does here (I found no explanation for pwm-2chan or audremap, but a *lot* of other stuff about it that was way to confusing and overwhelming) or the fact that I have to write an entirely separate question due to StackExchange's reputation requirements for commenting are driving me insane.

I am running a Raspberry Pi 4 Model B with RetroPie 4.7.1 installed. My config.txt file only contains the following: (there are the usual comments between them)

```
disable_overscan=1
hdmi_force_hotplug=1
hdmi_group=1
hdmi_mode=19
dtparam=audio=on

[pi4]
dtoverlay=vc4-fkms-v3d
max_framebuffers=2

disable_splash=1
```

If someone knowledgeable could please explain what dtoverlay does here, or could tell me what I'm doing wrong, I would be very grateful.

Edit: I am also confused how the alternate functions of GPIO pins like 12, 13, 18 and 19 are assigned; Is that what func and func2 is?

Comment: Just use dtoverlay=audremap,pins_12_13 nothing else.

Comment: @CoderMike and I guess that output is selected by the Headphones option.  Why not make that an answer?

Answer (score 1):

"but the fact that there is no explanation anywhere"

The README file in `/boot/overlays/` describes all the options and there is plenty of documentation in [config-txt](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/config-txt/)

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me on a raspberry pi zero

dtparam=audio=on

dtoverlay=audremap,enable_jack

dtoverlay=pwm-2chan,pin=18,func=2